# Is it possible to define mandatory statements in any order in ANTLR4?

Tags: regex, antlr, antlr4

Is it possible to define mandatory statements in any order in ANTLR4?

If I do

```
 module_header_stmts :  (
      yang_version_stmt stmtsep
    | namespace_stmt stmtsep
    | prefix_stmt stmtsep
 )+ ;
```

it's OK for any order of statements, but they're not mandatory as I would need.

If I do

```
 module_header_stmts :  
       yang_version_stmt stmtsep
       namespace_stmt stmtsep
       prefix_stmt stmtsep
 ;
```

then all of them are mandatory, but I can't give them any order.
Any help?

Comment: You could write out all possible orderings of the statement in the grammar but it would be better to add validation step after parsing. If anything it will make your error messages easier to read.

Comment: Yes I know about this option, but I would like to avoid it if possible

Comment: Then there is no solution. Aside from explicitly declaring all possible orderings in the grammar you can't express both constraints in a single parse tree.